# What is Recent Users in flurry?

Tags: android, ios, analytics, flurry

A question about ["Recent users"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z0YJ.jpg) in Flurry Analytics.

I just can't really understand what "Recent Users" mean in flurry. The definition given by flurry is:

"A recent user is defined as a user that has had a session with your application in the past seven days. Hence, a user who used the application only once in the past week is counted as a recent user just the same as a user who uses it everyday.

This graph plots two different data series. The first is the total number of new users seen each day. *The second is how many of the users who were new on that given day were active in the past seven days.* Note that all users who were new in the past seven days are recent.

Please Note: The New Users metric used in this calculation may be different from that of the New Users metrics on other pages due to timing differences. We calculate a different New Users figure to ensure that the Recent Users and New Users metrics used to calculate Recent Users are always in sync."

Okay, I get what a new user means - A new user is a user who has just started using your application. **But how can a NEW user be active in the past seven days?**

Answer (score 0):

In Flurry a 'New User' is any user that began using the app during the time frame you have selected, even if that time frame spans months or years of data.

The blue line charts the number of 'new users' who installed your app on a given day, week or month. The green line charts how many of those users had a session with your app in the past seven days.

Most of Flurry's other retention data only goes back 30 days so Recent Users is the best way to gauge the retention of users further back in time.

Comment: I think I got it! So, for example, blue line shows that we got 20 new users on 10.10.2015 and the green line shows that 5 of them were active in past seven days!  Thank you!